# How to know from which View the Edit form was invoked

Tags: 2010, javascript, list-view, edit-form

I want the edit form to behave differently on different list views. Therefore I have attached JavaScript to the list edit form. The problem is how can I differentiate from which view it was invoked?

Answer (score 0):

You could try `document.referrer` but it isn't failsave when used in combo with MDS

Better is to attach an URL parameter to the Edit buttons in the View